# How to divide command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments

If I have a program that gets an undefined number of integer command line arguments how can I get the result of the division of all the arguments one after another? With what do I have to initialize div? (if it's done this way)

```
if(args.length>0) {
        for(String i:args) {

            div/=Double.parseDouble(i);
        }
        System.out.println(div);
    }    else System.out.println("No arguments");
```

Comment: in what language? Java, as your name hints?

Comment: Read about [mcve] and improve your Q. Don't make us waste our time playing 20 questions to understand your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, in Java language.

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate it manually, for 1/2/3/4 you first take 1, then divide it by 2, 3 etc. So you should take 1st argument and divide to 2..n sequentially.
As far as I remember, argument 0 is the program path/name so should be skipped.

Try first initialise:

```
div = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
```

Then iterate the rest:

```
for (int i = 2; i < args.size(); i++) div /= Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
```